# PCAP Alternatives

Tags: pcap, winpcap

Are there any alternatives to PCAP DLL for capturing packets, that are not drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, the windows API as it stands doesn't expose that kind of information. The winPCAP driver is necessary to get into the kernel. Even the more modern network analysis software like wireshark still requires the driver (on windows, at least).

Comment: Can you open a raw socket in the windows API?

Answer (score 0):

Far away from the original post, you now have **NPCap** which is compatible **NDIS 6**
https://nmap.org/npcap/

This information could help a lot of network experts. NPCap is compatible with WireShark.